# new Bitcoin Core (0.13.2) as Cold Storage Wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, coldstorage

What are the instructions (in GUI or CLI) to setup and use the new Bitcoin Core (0.13.2) as Cold Storage Wallet? OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core does not officially support cold storage. That doesn't mean it can't be used for it, but if you don't know what you're doing you are likely to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

consider this:

- start with a blank wallet (ie no transactions) you can do that by moving the wallet .dat file elsewhere, upon start bitcoin core will create a new one
- encrypt your empty wallet (dont forget your password)
- send money to the address(es) in the wallet
- move wallet.dat onto a few usb sticks, put them in a safe
- delete wallet.dat from computer permanently

that could be considered cold storage :)